# Django-queryset get one object per field=foo

Tags: database, django, api, django-queryset

I have a basic FK to user, call it owner

```
class Baz(models.Model):

    owner = models.ForeignKeyField(User)


    ....
    ....
```

Now, with a queryset of Baz's, is there something that I can chain that will give me only one Baz per owner?

Comment: So, given a QuerySet of Baz, you want to filter it such that no two objects returned by the QuerySet have the same User object as owner. Is that what you want?

Comment: Sounds like you have the idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably not the best solution (would like to keep it out of memory and in querysets) but:

```
>>> d={}
>>> [d.setdefault(str(a.owner),a) for a in qs ]
>>> d.values()
```

does return a list of objects, the latest for each owner.  I have real reservations about the scalability of this solution.

Comment: I would suggest using this solution and then optimizing it later when it becomes a problem, maybe make a note to come back to this and fix it later.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using this too even though I hate it. If you do improve this code, can you please post your improvement?

Answer (score 2):

The function you are truly looking for is GROUP BY. However, Django does not typically support building querysets that do not directly output model instances. In this situation, you have two approachs:

```
Baz.objects.values('owner').distinct()
```

This will net you each distinct owner, but not the Baz object itself.

```
Baz.objects.filter(pk__in=Baz.objects.values('owner').distinct())
```

The above will perform a subquery (at least in MySQL) and should give the intended results, but isn't the most efficient way to retrieve it.

Lastly, since aggregates have been added, it may be possible for you to write a custom aggregate class which would work as a kind of "Distinct" and simply "GROUP BY ".

Comment: Ah ya the subquery isn't quite right, use the following group by whichi s shown below.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the question is how to run the equivalent of this:

```
SELECT * FROM myapp_baz GROUP BY owner_id;
```

Which will return one row for each unique owner_id.

It looks like this does the trick:

```
qs = Baz.objects.all()
qs.query.group_by = ['owner_id']

# Seems to do the trick
print [item for item in qs]
```

Comment: seems so close, I will look into this further.

column "app_baz.X" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet?  In my example, 'owner_id' is a column in the database (and if your Baz object has "owner = ForeignKey(SomeObject)" then you should have an owner_id column as well).

Comment: owner_id is a column, I get

ProgrammingError: column "checkins_checkin.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

checkins_checkin.id is the primary key .. but then, if I add that to the group_by list then it moves on to having the same error for the nex field.

Comment: Is the model we're working with Checkin, or is that another fk?  Also, fwiw, I'm working with Django 1.1 here.

Comment: this does work nicely for simple cases; other items on this page are germaine to situations where ordering takes place...

Comment: further note on ordering - assuming you always want something like the most recent entry (which happens pretty often!), a quick and useful cheat is to define the class ordering in the model's Meta data, e.g.

class Meta:
        ordering = ["-date_updated"]

then you can combine tvon's solution with an ordering without using Django's 'order_by' which has a tendency to ruin groupings, distinct queries...pretty much everything.

Comment: It does not work anymore with Django 2.2 and probably also later versions in 2022.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: This has a higher chance of working:

```
CheckIn.objects.extra(where=['checkins_checkin.id = (SELECT MAX(checkins_checkin.id) FROM checkins_checkin temp, auth_user WHERE auth_user.id = temp.id AND temp.user_id = checkins_checkin.user_id)',]).count()
```

Comment: CheckIn.objects.extra(where=['checkins_checkin.id = (SELECT checkins_checkin.id FROM checkins_checkin temp, auth_user WHERE auth_user.id = temp.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)',]).count()
Out[4]: 18

In [5]: CheckIn.objects.all().count()
Out[5]: 18

Comment: there are only 2 owners in this test dataset but I get back all 18 objects with that query.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to add the user criteria in the where clause. I updated my answer accordingly.